# JRebel Tomcat + Websphere

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, websphere, jrebel

Can I tell my Intellij to rebuild .class for tomcat and in Webpshere jar files?

My module configuration:

```
  <application generated-by="intellij" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://update.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/rebel-2_1.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="C:/Workspace/Project/pro-commands/target/classes">
        </dir>
        <jar name="C:/Workspace/WAS8.5/profiles/project/installedApps/pckserkowskiNode01Cell/project-test.ear/pro-commands-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        </jar>
    </classpath>

</application>
```

`<dir>` work for Tomcat but `<jar>` for Websphere is never used.

Comment: Please clarify, what are you trying to do? (Shift)-F9 (re)builds the project in IntelliJ IDEA, but then you're asking about JRebel configuration. So what's your real goal?

Comment: Or maybe you want to reload the classes in Tomcat and WebSphere at the same time?

Comment: I want to reload the classes in Tomcat and WebSphere at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload classes in Tomcat and WebSphere at the same time, you need to deploy the application with rebel.xml that points to the location where your IDE compiles those classes to.

I think your mistake is that you think that the configuration file is used to point at the application which should be reloaded? No!

Instead, The rebel.xml configuration file is used by JRebel agent to reconfigure the classloader to load the resources from the locations which are specified in the configuration file.

The first entry in your example is probably correct, since the classes are reloaded. What's missing, probably, is rebel.xml in the application that is deployed in WebSphere. if you need to reload the classes that reside in the jar, please make sure that rebel.xml is packaged into the root of the jar file. Then it should work just fine.

If you are 100% sure that the configuration file is there, and you still do not see that the classes are reloaded, please contact JRebel support team at support@zeroturnaround.com -- they will assist on troubleshooting the issue.